# Other ways of declaring a PHP class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, woocommerce

I am writing a complex product type in Woocommerce, I don't like the way most WordPress codes looks(a bit messy by default to me and it is 'not poetic') so I decided to use PHP namespace and autoloading. So I have to declare my Product Type class in the scope where WordPress can pick it up. The following is the facto way of doing this.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    class WC_Product_Partner_Aware extends \WC_Product_Variable{
        // Content here is very large and seems very awkward to be in a file call function.php that contains other actions and filters
    }
});
```

I will like to declare this class in a namespace such has `App/ProductType/` I have tried everything nothing is working, I tried the following code as well out of frustration

```
add_action('init', function(){
    define('WC_Product_Partner_Aware', 'App/ProductType/PartnerAwareProduct');
});
```

Can anyone help? I will like to be a code poet but WordPress is making this stanza not to rhyme.

Comment: how you manage your autoloading ? why not use require ?

Comment: @Yanis-git It makes the code to appear neater and having not to worry about `require` makes life easier in large projects

Answer (score 2):

You can seperate your class outside of the init function.  Just make sure its available when the init function is ran.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    // you can call class with namespace if desired
    if(class_exists(\some\namespace\WC_Product_Partner_Aware)){
        $ppa = new \some\namespace\WC_Product_Partner_Aware();
        $ppa->doStuff();
    }

});
```

WC_Product_Partner_Awre.php

```
namespace some\namespace;
class WC_Product_Partner_Aware extends \WC_Product_Variable{
   //your properties and methods.
}
```